# Match the alphanumeric words(NOT NUMERIC-ONLY words) which have unique digits

Tags: javascript, regex

Using regular expression, I want to select only the **words** which:

- are alphanumeric
- do not contain only numbers
- do not contain only alphabets
- have unique numbers(1 or more)

I am not really good with the regex but so far, I have tried [`[^\d\s]*(\d+)(?!.*\1)`](https://regex101.com/r/TimjdW/2) which takes me nowhere close to the desired output :(

Here are the input strings:

```
I would like abc123 to match but not 123.
ab12s should also match
Only number-words like 1234 should not match
Words containing same numbers like ab22s should not match
234 should not match
hel1lo2haha3hoho4
hel1lo2haha3hoho3
```

Expected Matches:

```
abc123
ab12s
hel1lo2haha3hoho4
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use

```
\b(?=\d*[a-z])(?=[a-z]*\d)(?:[a-z]|(\d)(?!\w*\1))+\b
```

https://regex101.com/r/TimjdW/3

Anchor the start and end of the pattern at word boundaries with `\b`, then:

- `(?=\d*[a-z])` - Lookahead for an alphabetical character somewhere in the word
- `(?=[a-z]*\d)` - Lookahead for a digit somewhere in the word
- `(?:[a-z]|(\d)(?!\w*\1))+` Repeatedly match either:

  - `[a-z]` - Any alphabetical character, or
  - `(\d)(?!\w*\1)` - A digit which does not occur again in the same word

Answer (score 3):

Here is a bit shorter & faster regex to make it happen since it doesn't assert negative lookahead for each character:

```
/\b(?=[a-z]*\d)(?=\d*[a-z])(?!\w*(\d)\w*\1)[a-z\d]+\b/ig
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/avSYuv/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\b`: Word boundary
- `(?=[a-z]*\d)`: Make sure we have at least a digit
- `(?=\d*[a-z])`: Make sure we have at least a letter
- `(?!\w*(\d)\w*\1)`: Make sure digits are not repeated anywhere in the word
- `[a-z\d]+`: Match 1+ alphanumericals
- `\b`: Word boundary

Comment: @ManJoey: I believe the that selected regex will be slower for bigger strings

Comment: @anubhava, `1` in `(?!\w*(\d)\w*\1)` means `(\d)` saved in memory's first buffer(like `sed`) kind of thing, sorry I am learning regex so thought to check with you on same once.

Comment: Yes that's correct. `\1` is back-reference for captured group #1 i.e. `(\d)`

Answer (score 2):

You could assert all the conditions using one negative lookahead:

```
\b(?![a-z]+\b|\d+\b|\w*(\d)\w*\1)[a-z\d]+\b
```

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/79RQmK/3)

The important parts are starting match from `\b` and immediately looking for the conditions:

- `[a-z]+\b` Only alphabetic
- `\d+\b` Only numeric
- `\w*(\d)\w*\1` Has a repeating digit

Comment: Thanks, good fix though not sure why one single negative lookahead with alternations shows more steps (as in my answer) than multiple assertions on regex101

Comment: @anubhava Yes, it depends on the input string. For example consider switching the first two lookaheads in your solution. You'll see [it increases](https://regex101.com/r/avSYuv/2).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
\b(?!\w*(\d)\w*\1)(?=(?:[a-z]+\d+)|(?:\d+[a-z]+))[a-z0-9]+\b
```

- `\b` - Word boundary.
- `(?!\w*(\d)\w*\1)` - Condition to check unique digits.
- `(?=(?:[a-z]+\d+)|(?:\d+[a-z]+))` - Condition to check alphanumeric words.
- `[a-z0-9]+` - Matches `a to z` and `0 to 9`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HzWbbc/2/)

Comment: Looking at all the answers here reminds me why I think regexes aren't the best way to solve this sort of problem…  They're highly ingenious, but I'd hate to have to debug or maintain any of them!

Comment: @gidds You can approach them the same way you approach *any* programming problem - break the problem down into logical groups, (re?)write and verify each group, and put it together into a single pattern. REs are a great concise way to match strings - they're extremely flexible and mostly language agnostic, which is a huge plus. As long as the pattern to debug has descriptive comments (like in the answers here), it shouldn't be hard at all for someone with a bit of experience with REs, IMO